# Default answer from sum of two ranges input

Tags: jquery, html

So...I tried to make a little calculator with help from the Round Slider jQuery plugin.
I've done it until this point, but I have a few things I want to implement, but I can't get the hold of them.

You can see the demo live at the bottom.
So when you drag on the first slider, a calculation it's made. When you switch to 'No' and drag the second slider, another calculation it's made.

My questions are:

1. When you first arrive on the site, how can I have a default value? Like...the first slider to have a 80k value and the final answer to be showed after the roundslider. So to have a default value and then you can drag the slider left or right.
2. The sliders have some steps, like between 0 and 100k a 10k step and furthermore. But as you can see it's really difficult to select a value between 0 and 100k, because the length of slider between 0 and 1mil it's much smaller. It's there a solution so it can be easier to select values from 0 to 1mil?
3. When you check 'No' another calculation it's made but if you select a value on slider 2 and then check 'Yes' it's still showing the answer from calculation for two sliders, instead of showing just the first slider calculation. It's there anything I can do so it reversed when i go from 'No' to 'Yes'?
4. Last one just for pure curiosity. As you can see I managed to put commas between the number, but they only appear when you finished selecting the value. If you drag the thumb left right, the values that appear in right are without commas. It's there a solution for this?

Here is a fiddle with my HTML and jQuery code. I will post the HTML code here aswell, but the jQuery code it's in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1t9vyy6s/

HTML

```
<section class="grafic-width">

    <div class="grafic-row">
        <p class="latime">R&D Spend</p>
        <form onsubmit="return false" oninput="level.value = flevel.valueAsNumber">
              <input name="flevel" id="flying1" type="range" min="0" max="5000000" step="10000" value="80000" onchange="add_two_number();">
              <label class="right-align">
              <p>$</p><output id="slider1out" for="flying1" name="level"></output><p></p>
              </label>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="grafic-row">
        <p class="latime-auto">Was your business profitable?</p>
        <div class="form">
            <p>Yes</p>
                    <label class="switch">
                        <input id="js--checkbox" type="checkbox">
                        <div class="slider round"></div>
                    </label>
            <p>No</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grafic-row" id="slider2">
        <p class="latime">Business Losses</p>
        <form onsubmit="return false" oninput="level.value = flevel.valueAsNumber">
              <input name="flevel" id="flying2" type="range" min="0" max="5000000" step="10000" value="80000" onchange="add_two_number();">
              <p>$</p><output id="slider2out" for="flying2" name="level"></output><p></p>
        </form>
    </div>

        <div class="types">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="control">
                        <div id="shape"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

LIVE: http://alex.the3.ro/jquery.html

Comment: your jsfiddle is not working, 1. call add_two_numbers function(), 2. should be a css thing, increase the length, 3. check if the checkbox is checked and then do calculations on add_new_number function, 4. tie you Number_with_comma function to change event of the slider

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site. Also, please read [ask] and note that we prefer to have a single question per question. Currently this question is too broad. See the [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 1):

So for the first two items:

1. You would want to set the value of the slider on load using the `val();` method like so:

   ```
   $('document').ready(function() {
     $('#flying1').val('80000');
   });
   ```
2. in your plugin, roundSlider, use `step` so add this (http://roundsliderui.com/document.html#step):

   ```
   $("#shape").roundSlider({
       sliderType: "min-range",
       editableTooltip: false,
       radius: 105,
        width: 16,
       value: "answer",
       handleSize: 0,
       handleShape: "square",
       circleShape: "half-top",
       startAngle: 0,

       /*detirmines intervals*/
       step: 1000000,

       tooltipFormat: "changeTooltip"
   });
   ```